# Picking a person with specified characteristics in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, task

I have an assignment in which I am given information about a person in one line of a .txt file, separated by a space (FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME AGE CITY) and I need to print out all people from a certain city and older than 18. So the full file would look something like this:

FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME CITY AGE

FIRST_NAME2 LAST_NAME2 CITY2 AGE2

FIRST_NAME3 LAST_NAME3 CITY3 AGE3

P.S. Here it's wrong - it should be AGE then CITY. This is the exact file screenshot:

[File screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Quk.png)

I tried separating first just one line as a sentence, then tokenizing it using strtok(), puting each token in its array of the same information (names, surnames, cities, ages) and lastly comparing ages and cities to the requested ones. However, I can't get tokens into arrays. So, could somebody help me with this way of doing the task (if it`s correct) or somebody may have another way of doing it?

This is the code for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
int i=0; //numerer
int pos=0;
char info[100]; // all info about one person
char imena[500];     //names
char prezimena[500];  //surnames
int godine[500];      //years
char mesto[500];     //cities


FILE *pok;
pok=fopen("C:/Users/Trajkovici/Desktop/OsobeFajl.txt","r");
if(pok==NULL)
{
    printf("Greška prilikom otvaranja datoteke!");
}
fscanf(pok,"%[^\n]",&info);



puts("INFO: ");
puts(info);    //dispalying full info
fclose(pok);

char * token = strtok(info, " ");
 
while( token != NULL || i<4) 
{
puts("\nTOKEN:");
printf( " %s\n", token );
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
i++;
}

}
```

If this is the right way, how can I get the tokens into arrays?

Comment: Please do not show pictures of plain text. Just copy&paste as formatted text into your question. Also proper formatting is important. Not for the compiler but for the readers. Especially for beginners. You can use the `edit` button below your question to improve the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you supposed to store all the file content somewhere? Otherweise you don't need any of your arrays. Just tokenize the line you read and to whatever you need to do with it. Don't bother with storing it.

Comment: StackOverflow can only work well if you provide feedback to comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not mention anything except printing some of the data, there is no need to store anything in your program.

This makes things a lot easier.
Your program could look like this:
(Some errors marked)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// main() has return type int, not void.
// As you need to provide a city for filtering I assume you take it as command line argument

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "No city name provided.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char *city_filter = argc[1];
  char info[100]; // all info about one person

  FILE *pok = fopen("C:/Users/Trajkovici/Desktop/OsobeFajl.txt","r");
  if (pok==NULL)
  {
    perror("Greška prilikom otvaranja datoteke!");
// If you detect this error you mustn't continue your program as you would use the NULL pointer in functions.
    exit(1);
  }

// You must read more than just one line
// Now we continue as long as we read a value
// You must also provide some limit to prevent buffer overflow
  while (fscanf(pok,"%99[^\n]",&info) == 1)
  {
    puts("INFO: ");
    puts(info);    //dispalying full info

    char *firstname;
    char *lastname;
    char *city;
    char *age_string;

// You must check for errors.
// For readability I skip this. ;)

    firstname = strtok(info, " ");
    lastname = strtok(NULL, " ");
    age_string = strtok(NULL, " ");
    city = strtok(NULL, " ");

    char *end = NULL;
    age = strtod(age_string, &end, 10);

    // Filter output
    // older than 18 and from a certain city...
    if (age > 18 && !strcmp(city, city_filter))
    {
      printf("First: %s, last: %s, age: %d\n", firstname, lastname, age);
    }
  }
  fclose(pok);
}
```

The code is not tested.

If you need to store the data for later use, you must provide storage for all entries.
For this you should define a structure that holds all data of one person.
Then make an array of that struct.
This is much more readable than creating arrays for each field.